# Remove files by regular expression

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression, filenames, wildcards

I want to keep files whose names match `[0-9A-Z]{1,2}_\d{4}_\w+?\.dat`, for example, `A1_2001_pm23aD.dat`, `K_1998_12.dat`, and remove the rest.

However, the `ls` and `rm` commands do not support such regexes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' !([[:digit:][:upper:]]?([[:digit:][:upper:]])_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]_+([[:alnum:]]).dat)
```

this will print all file/directory names that do not (`!`) match `[[:digit:][:upper:]]` followed by zero or one `[[:digit:][:upper:]]` followed by 4 `[[:digit:]]` in between `_`s and then one or more `[[:alnum:]]` before the extension `.dat`.
If you want to search recursively:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' **/!([[:digit:][:upper:]]?([[:digit:][:upper:]])_[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]]_+([[:alnum:]]).dat)
```

Alternatively, with `gnu find` (you can use a regex):

```
find . -regextype egrep ! -regex '.*/[[:digit:][:upper:]]{1,2}_[[:digit:]]{4}_[[:alnum:]]+\.dat$'
```

Comment: look good except the terribly looong regex :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of doing this. You could use a scripting language that understands regular expressions. For example, in Perl:

```
perl -le 'unlink(grep(!/[0-9A-Z]{1,2}_\d{4}_\w+?.dat/,@ARGV))' *
```

That will look for all files (**not subdirectories**) in the current directory, collect those that don't match the regex and delete them.

You could also do a similar thing with bash, you just need to translate the regex to POSIX ERE:

```
for f in *; do 
    [[ "$f" =~ [0-9A-Z]{1,2}_[0-9]{4}_[a-zA-Z0-9]+.dat ]] || rm "$f"; 
done
```

Note that in your regex, `\w+?.dat` will try to match the smallest possible alphanumeric string *any character* and `dat`. I don't see why you would want to use `+?` here and you probably meant to use `\.dat`. I am guessing you also probably want to make sure the entire file name matches, so that things like `foobarfoobarfoobarA1_2001_pm23aD.datfoobarfooabr` are also removed. If so, use one of these instead:

```
perl -le 'unlink(grep(!/^[0-9A-Z]{1,2}_\d{4}_\w+\.dat$/,@ARGV))' *
```

or

```
for f in *; do 
    [[ "$f" =~ ^[0-9A-Z]{1,2}_[0-9]{4}_[a-zA-Z0-9]+.dat$ ]] || rm "$f"; 
done
```

Finally, to also delete directories, you could do:

```
for f in *; do 
    [[ "$f" =~ ^[0-9A-Z]{1,2}_[0-9]{4}_[a-zA-Z0-9]+.dat$ ]] || rm -rf "$f"; 
done
```

Comment: yes, you are correct. I forgot to escape `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended \
            -type f ! -regex '.*/[0-9A-Z]{1,2}_[[:digit:]]{4}_[[:alnum:]_]+?\.dat' -delete
```

- Of course you can put it all on one line
  (removing the `\` at the end of the first line).
- `-regextype posix-egrep` seems to work exactly as well
  as `-regextype posix-extended`.
- If your version of `find` doesn't support `-delete`,
  use `-exec rm -- {} +` or `-exec rm -- {} ';'`.
- If you want to search only the top-level directory, use `-maxdepth 1`.